Next js (node ​20.14.0) Error when starting debugging on VS Code
I have problem when i try run debuging on my next js project in VS Code.
After click "Bug" icon on dev script i have fallowing error:

I've already tried removing node_modules, package-lock.json and using npm install but nothing works ;(

were you able to figure this out?

Unfortunately not
